# Overreleased MPMoviePlayerController under ARC in iOS SDK 8.4 on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, sdk, automatic-ref-counting, mpmovieplayercontroller

Created a very simple (single view) sample project from a part of a bigger one. **It worked with the iOS SDK 8.3.**

When you hit the "Show me" button, a video comes up (as modal) and 2 secs later, it disappears. Looks good. But few moments later the app crashes because a -dealloc message is sent to an already deallocated object.

> [MPAVController release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Here's my sample project (don't forget about the Video.mp4):

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "MediaViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Show me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    MediaViewController *mediaVC = [[MediaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:mediaVC animated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissPresentedController) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }];
}

- (void)dismissPresentedController
{
    [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

MediaViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MediaViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

MediaViewController.m

```
#import "MediaViewController.h"

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MediaViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *movieController;

@end

@implementation MediaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Video" withExtension:@"mp4"]];
    movieController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    movieController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    self.movieController = movieController;

    UIView *movieView = movieController.view;
    movieView.frame = CGRectZero;
    movieView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view insertSubview:movieView atIndex:0];

    // Autolayout

    NSDictionary *layoutNeededViews = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(movieView);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[movieView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:layoutNeededViews]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[movieView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:layoutNeededViews]];
}

@end
```

If I turn off the ARC, the bug is still alive (adding -fno-objc-arc flag for the MediaViewController.m and adding this line

```
[movieController release];
```

after the property assign.

Also checked with Instruments:
[image: Instruments check for Zombie objects]

The issue occurs on **iPad** (all the time) but it seems not a problem on iPhone.

Has anyone faced this issue?

(Probably a solution: download the iOS 8.3 SDK and make archive with that)

Cheers,

Adam

Comment: After I re-downloaded the Xcode 6.3.2 (with iOS SDK 8.3) and just ran from ~/Downloads/... I was sill getting that crash. 
After the Xcode 6.4 was zipped (and the source was deleted), the 6.3.2 moved to it's place (/Applications/) it worked fine.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too with 8.4. Even using archives built from xcode 6.3. I see the same issue in ios-9.0 beta.

Comment: Have you opened a Radar about this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm.. maybe I got a fix for that, just try it (it already works for me - did many tests)

Try this:
On your `MediaViewController` add/override `viewDidDisappear` method like this:

```
   func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        //just a small fix for error on iPad iOS8.4
        self.movieController.stop()
    }
```

If it don't works add it also in  `viewWillDisappear` - worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it's being over released?

Comment: something goes wrong at releasing of the viewcontroller...so its a bug anyway....

Answer (score 1):

My app works fine on ios8.3, but is showing this over-release issue on 8.4. I'd assumed I'd broken something until having read your question I tried the app on ios8.3

Comment: Been testing this some more. I seem to be having the issue on the simulator, but not an iPad running 8.4

Comment: I can just confirm - but I was sure I tried it on device as well - it doesn't crash on my iPad mini (iOS 8.4).
Still not sure it's "safe to release" with this SDK...

Comment: Raised a radar: 21701131

Comment: @Jmf: Please cross-post your radar to [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/) so others can more easily dupe it.

Comment: i am also facing issue it seems who all are using presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated to show full screen video are having issues in 8.4 but if you add movie player as subview it works fine. I am also going through the same problem and trying to fix it. see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311636/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-not-playing-videos-for-ios-8-4

Comment: just look at my answer below..maybe it will help